# Unable to unmarshal xml node name with golang

Tags: xml, go

I want to learn how to unmarshal xml documents with golang.

Let's say I have a file called `athletes.xml` with this content:

```
<athletes>
  <boxer>
    <name>John</name>
  </boxer>
  <boxer>
    <name>Sam</name>
  </boxer>
  <gymnast>
    <name>Jessica</name>
  </gymnast>
</athletes>
```

I wrote the following golang code to try to print each athlete name and their athlete type

```
package main

import (
        "encoding/xml"
        "fmt"
        "io/ioutil"
        "os"
)

type Athlete struct {
        Type string `xml:"-"`
        // Type xml.Name `xml:",any"` // also tried this
        Name string `xml:"name"`
}

type AthletesWrapper struct {
        XMLName  xml.Name   `xml:"athletes"`
        Athletes []Athlete `xml:",any"`
}

func main() {
        xmlFile, _ := os.Open("athletes.xml")
        defer xmlFile.Close()

        xmlContent, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(xmlFile)

        var athletesWrapper AthletesWrapper

        _ = xml.Unmarshal(xmlContent, &athletesWrapper)

        fmt.Println("Parent Node Name: ", athletesWrapper.XMLName)
        for _, athlete := range athletesWrapper.Athletes {
                fmt.Println("Type: ", athlete.Type)
                fmt.Println("Name: ", athlete.Name)
        }
}
```

But this line  `fmt.Println("Type: ", athlete.Type)` is always empty.  What did I do wrong?  How do I make sure `athlete.Type` has the appropriate value?

Comment: `xml:"-"` omits the field from unmarshal and marshal, so "what did I do wrong?", you explicitly told `encoding/xml` to ignore that field. And as far as I know there's no way to unmarshal the tag name as a field value _with just struct tags_. You'll need to implement the `xml.Unmarshaler` interface to get access to the XML tag and its name.

Comment: Example of how to do it with a custom unmarshaler: https://go.dev/play/p/WAwKGrZxnLf

Comment: @mkopriva - perfect! that puts me in the right direction, very much appreciated